# Dataframe value comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data-frame like this

[image]

I want to compare a with c and b with d.
When there is a nan or empty value, it will be considered as 0.
[image]

I tried to use list comprehension but receive `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

```
df['bVsd']=["True" if df['b']==df['d'] else "False"]
```

Comment: Just use `df['bVsd']= df['b']==df['d']`.

Answer (score 3):

**ADDED ANSWER FOR YOUR 2ND QUESTION**

To achieve what you want to do, simply compare the columns directly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,5,7,9],
                   'b':[0,0,0,0,0],
                   'c':[1,3,5,7,9],
                   'd':[0,np.nan,np.nan,0,np.nan]})

# Fill the nan and empty cells with 0
df = df.fillna(0)

# To do the comparison you desire
df['aVsc'] = (df['a'] == df['c'])
df['bVsc'] = (df['b'] == df['d'])
```

The reason why you are getting the error is because `df['b'] == df['d']` returns you a series:

```
    0
0   True
1   True
2   True
3   True
4   True
```

and thus it is ambiguous to evaluate the boolean value of a series, unless you specify `any` or `all`, which would not be doing you what you want either way.

And lastly, on a separate note, that was not the correct way of doing list comprehension. It should have an iterator and you need to loop over the iterator. Something like this:  `[True if i == 'something' else False for i in iterator]`.

**2nd Question**

If you want `df['aVsc]` to be 0 when `df['a'] == df['c']`, and `df['aVsc] == df['a']` otherwise, you can use `np.where`:

```
df['aVsc'] = np.where(df['a'] == df['c'], 0, df['a'])
```

in which the `np.where` function means check if condition `df['a'] == df['c']` is `True`, if it is, assign the value of `0` else, assign the value of `df['a']`.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to say When it is True df['aVsc'] = 0 otherwise, df['aVsc']=df['a'] value.